# MouseMove performance slow using GetPosition

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, transform

I have a Canvas control with various elements on, in this particular function I am allowing a user to drag the end point of a line around the canvas.  In the MouseMove function I call `e.GetPosition()`.

The function is, according to the VS performance analyzer, close to 30% of total CPU for the app when constantly moving around. Its pretty slow.  What can I do to increase this performance?

```
CurrentPoint = e.GetPosition(PointsCanvas);
```

Comment: `in this particular function I am allowing a user to drag the end point of a line around the canvas` - I would rather use a `Thumb` for that and handle the `DragDelta` event.

Comment: @HighCore could you explain a little more what you mean? thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same problem while using **MouseMove** on windows phone 8. It seems that while dragging , events  (containing the coordinates you need ) are raised at regular time interval ( depending on what you do in the implementation in your listeners, every 20 ms for example). So what I did was to populate a [Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.aspx) with my coordinates and create a Thread that consume that Queue by enqueue the first element and do the logic I want. Like that the logic is not done serially because it's another thread who does the job.
I don't know if I'm enough clear so please take a look to the code below :

```
//Class used to store e.getPosition(UIElement).X/Y
public class mouseInformation
    {
        public int x { get; set; }
        public int y { get; set; }


        public mouseInformation(int x, int y, String functionName)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;              
        }
    }



    private readonly Queue<mouseInformation> queueOfEvent = new Queue<mouseInformation>();

    //MouseMove listener
    private void wpCanvas_MouseDragged(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //Instead of "wpCanvas" put the name of your UIElement (here your canvas name)
        mouseInformation mouseDragged = new mouseInformation((int)e.GetPosition(wpCanvas).X, (int)e.GetPosition(wpCanvas).Y);

        EnqueueMouseEvent(mouseDragged);

    }

    //Allow you to add a MouseInformation object in your Queue
    public void EnqueueMouseEvent(mouseInformation mi)
    {

        lock (queueOfEvent)
        {
            queueOfEvent.Enqueue(mi);
            Monitor.PulseAll(queueOfEvent);
        }
    }

    //Logic that your consumer thread will do
    void Consume()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            mouseInformation MI;

            lock (queueOfEvent)
            {          
                while (queueOfEvent.Count == 0) Monitor.Wait(queueOfEvent);
                MI = queueOfEvent.Dequeue();  
            }

                // DO YOUR LOGIC HERE
                // i.e  DoSomething(MI.x, MI.y)               
        }
    }
```

And don't forget to create the thread in your Main() or in MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) method if you are Windows phone user.

```
 System.Threading.ThreadStart WatchQueue = new System.Threading.ThreadStart(Consume);
 System.Threading.Thread RunWatchQueue = new System.Threading.Thread(WatchQueue);
 RunWatchQueue.Name = "Events thread";
 RunWatchQueue.Start();
```

To be simple less you do in your **MouseMove** listener, more speed it will be.
You can aswell do the logic asynchronously or even use [Bresenham algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) to simulate more events.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any effects such as dropshaddow etc?
I recently had the situation where `e.GetPosition()` was also using 30% of the app's cpu resources, which doesn't make any sense right? 
I turns out that up the visual tree there was a control applying a dropshaddow effect and that was what was slowing everything down so much...