# Implementing stroke drawing similar to InkCanvas

Tags: wpf

My problem effectively boils down to accurate mouse movement detection.

I need to create my own implementation of an InkCanvas and have succeeded for the most part, except for drawing strokes accurately.

```cs
void OnMouseMove(object sneder, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var position = e.GetPosition(this);
    
    if (!Rect.Contains(position))
        return;
    
    var ratio = new Point(Width / PixelDisplay.Size.X, Height / PixelDisplay.Size.Y);
    var intPosition = new IntVector(Math2.FloorToInt(position.X / ratio.X), Math2.FloorToInt(position.Y / ratio.Y));

    DrawBrush.Draw(intPosition, PixelDisplay);
    UpdateStroke(intPosition); // calls CaptureMouse
}
```

This works. The Bitmap (PixelDisplay) is updated and all is well. However, any kind of quick mouse movement causes large skips in the drawing. I've narrowed down the problem to `e.GetPosition(this)`, which blocks the event long enough to be inaccurate.

There's [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16321755/mousemove-performance-slow-using-getposition/) question which is long beyond revival, and its answers are unclear or simply don't have a noticeable difference.
After some more testing, the stated solution and similar ideas fail specifically because of `e.GetPosition`.

I know InkCanvas uses similar methods after looking through the source; detect the device, if it's a mouse, get its position and capture. I see no reason for the same process to not work identically here.

Comment: In the link you provided, the highest score answer seems like it is on the right track. You want to make `OnMouseMove` as lightweight as possible because if you do too much UI processing in here, it will back up the incoming `OnMouseMove` events. So following their guidance, move all of your logic to update the UI on another thread. So in your case, once you call `e.GetPosition`, move the rest of your code into a new thread that will try to update the UI stroke (be sure to process it on the Dispacher UI thread).

Comment: @TamBui As I said, this solution doesn't apply. The delay is still very much visible, and I'm sure it's `e.GetPosition()` causing this.

Comment: If you believe it to be true, then what you should do is replace `e.GetPosition(this)` with a short fake method `MyFakePositionMovement(previousPosition)` where all you do is move the position just a little in a random X/y direction from the last position. This kind of logic should complete in micro/nano seconds. If the visible delay disappears, then you are correct that the root cause is `e.GetPosition()`. But if there is still a visible delay, then the root cause is in everything after `e.GetPosition()`.

Comment: @TamBui Yes, this is how I determined the source of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up being able to partially solve this.

```
position = getMousePosition()

if canvasRect does not contain position
    return

bitmapRatio = Vector2(elementWidth / bitmapSize.X, elementHeight / bitmapSize.Y);
bitmapPosition = Vector2(floor(position.X / bitmapRatio.X), floor(position.Y / bitmapRatio.Y))
// Calculate pixel coordinates based on the element size

lastDrawPoint = getLastDrawPoint() or null
// Uses System.Linq to grab the last stroke, if it exists

if lastDrawPoint is not null // Determine if we're in the middle of a stroke
    alphaDiff = 1 / Vector(bitmapPosition.X - lastDrawPoint.X, bitmapPosition.Y - lastDrawPoint.Y).Magnitude; 
// For some interpolation, calculate 1 / distance (magnitude) of the two points.
// Magnitude formula: Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(X, 2) + Math.Pow(Y, 2));
    alpha = 0;

    xDiff = bitmapPosition.X - lastDrawPoint.X;
    yDiff = bitmapPosition.Y - lastDrawPoint.Y;

    while (alpha < 1)
        alpha += alphaDiff

        adjustedPosition = new Vector(
            floor((position.X + (xDiff * alpha)) / bitmapRatio.X),
            floor((position.Y + (yDiff * alpha)) / bitmapRatio.Y));
        
        drawCurrentBrush(adjustedPosition)

drawCurrentBrush(bitmapPosition); // Draw the original point
setLastDrawPoint(bitmapPosition);
```

This implementation interpolates between the last point and the current one to fill in any gaps. It's not perfect when using a very small brush size for example, but is a solution nonetheless.

### Some remarks

`IntVector` is a lazily implemented Vector2 by me, just using integers instead.
`Math2` is a helper class. `FloorToInt` is short for `(int)MathF.Round(...))`